# Cannot publish library due to javadoc task errors

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

I have a library I'm trying to publish using the bintray plugin's `bintrayUpload` task. When the script runs the `javadoc` task, it is filled with many errors, because the `javadoc` task evidently cannot read references to classes in dependencies of my library module. For example:

```
error: package androidx.preference does not exist
    import androidx.preference.Preference;
```

When I run `gradlew javadoc`, it completes without errors. I'm not sure exactly how the `bintrayUpload` task operates. Is it calling that same `javadoc` task that I am? And either way, how do I configure it to be able to see the classes of my dependencies from androidx?

In my top level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
    }
}
```

In my library module's build.gradle:

```
apply from: '../bintray-setup.gradle'
```